# Language Code in Template inheritance

Tags: django, django-views

I'm inheriting base page into another page as below

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

I want to include language code in this

{{ request.LANGUAGE_CODE }} to load corresponding template. How to append language code along with "base.html"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `{% extends %}` template tag can accept a variable as the second parameter as well as a string.

Assuming you need to set this variable in every view, you could set this variable using [middleware or a context_processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/middleware/). If you only need to set this in a few views, you could just use a shared function to create the context variable you pass to `{% extends %}`